# constant move mesh (straw) along curve, only at desired distance [geometry nodes?]

Tags: geometry-nodes, loop, curve-modifier

[image]

Hi community,

I want to constantly move scattered geometry along the curve (**bending** straw) using geometry nodes. (picture above)

Similar to curve modifier x location offset but only on **selected distance**. It's quite common problem and I couldn't find any answer yet. *Probably the best and fastest results could be achieved using geometry nodes, but I'm open to other ideas too.*
Fading in and out (changing transparency locally using proximity node would be nice addition but not required)

**UPDATE:**
I found out simmilar example by youtuber Cartesian Caramel: Traffic system
https://youtu.be/yqTXiw6MJgI
[image]
It's near but:
**1**. geometry (straw) should bend on corners (like with array+ curve modifier setup)
2.Scattering is a bit odd-not uniform (packed all over one point)

I know some node setup must be added after straw geometry (my red mark, picture 2) to force it to bend, but I can't get to it yet and i haven't been able to incorporate any other bend mechanic to my example.
(like this: https://youtu.be/M-fOsAcGtFg)
Deform object along curve

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rotate Spheres according to height of other points](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/262932/rotate-spheres-according-to-height-of-other-points)

Comment: Or maybe "Shortest Path" and sample the resulting curve by a factor

Comment: Not exactly, but I updated post with my current knowledge and some example node setup (problem is lack of bending moving geometry accordingly to curve shape).

Comment: What you have combined with this might do the trick: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/245282/157965.